# How to create outbound messages programmatically in Salesforce? (Using Metadata API)

Tags: api, salesforce, metadata, apex, outbound

Is there a way to create outbound messages programmatically in Salesforce? for example a class in which make Metadata API call to create an outbound message?
Any code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in this moment Salesforce don't provide such functionality. Possible, there are some other solutions for your case, can you describe it more widely?